# Parse Facebook login pop up twice

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse 1.7.5 and Facebook SDK 20150708. I request for the permissions of public_profile and email. When I click the log in button, it jumps to the Facebook website for permission, after granted, it goes back to the log in page and the Facebook login button shows a loading icon and then it jumps to Facebook again for permission, I need to click on the ok button for the second time to finish the login process. Why do I have to grant the permissions for twice?

Here is my code:

```
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) {

    var permissions = [ "public_profile", "email" ]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions,  block: {  (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                self.loadUserData()
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("afterLogIn", sender: self)
            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("afterLogIn", sender: self)
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    })
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("afterLogIn", sender: self)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are implementing your code in "didloginuser" delegate method. Think logically, this method will be called right after user logged in. Which in your case happens the second time you are getting permissions page. So it means you need to look for another delegate method, and paste your code there. I am not sure which one exactly but check something like "will login" etc.